# Microsoft Graph API. Getting user activity

Tags: c#, api, rest, uwp, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I'm trying to create user activity from uwp application. But every time I encounter this response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-12-28T09:20:16",
            "request-id": "some id",
            "client-request-id": "some id"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my c# code example. Request content string was taken from [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/projectrome-put-activity?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
public sealed class UserActivityProvider : IUserActivityProvider
{
    private const string activityId = "SendMessageUserActivity";
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public UserActivityProvider()
    {
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(Account account)
    {
        var accessToken = string.Empty;

        var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(MicrosoftConstants.ClientId)
           .WithRedirectUri(MicrosoftConstants.RedirectUri)
           .Build();

        var scopes = new string[]
        {
            "UserActivity.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp"
        };

        AuthenticationResult? authToken = null;

        try
        {
            authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account.Email).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        }

        if (authToken != null)
        {
            accessToken = authToken.AccessToken;
        }

        return accessToken;
    }

    public async Task CreateUserActivityAsync(Account account, CreatingMessageUserActivityParameters userActivityParameters)
    {
        var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync(account);
        if (accessToken != string.Empty)
        {
            var contentForCreatingActivity = new StringContent("{\r\n  \"appActivityId\": \"SendMessageUserActivity\",\r\n  \"activitySourceHost\": \"https://www.contoso.com\",\r\n  \"userTimezone\": \"Africa/Casablanca\",\r\n  \"appDisplayName\": \"Contoso, Ltd.\",\r\n  \"activationUrl\": \"https://www.contoso.com/article?id=12345\",\r\n  \"contentUrl\": \"https://www.contoso.com/article?id=12345\",\r\n  \"fallbackUrl\": \"https://www.contoso.com/article?id=12345\",\r\n  \"contentInfo\": {\r\n    \"@context\": \"https://schema.org\",\r\n    \"@type\": \"Article\",\r\n    \"author\": \"Jennifer Booth\",\r\n    \"name\": \"How to Tie a Reef Knot\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"visualElements\": {\r\n    \"attribution\": {\r\n      \"iconUrl\": \"https://www.contoso.com/icon\",\r\n      \"alternateText\": \"Contoso, Ltd.\",\r\n      \"addImageQuery\": false\r\n    },\r\n    \"description\": \"How to Tie a Reef Knot. A step-by-step visual guide to the art of nautical knot-tying.\",\r\n    \"backgroundColor\": \"#ff0000\",\r\n    \"displayText\": \"Contoso How-To: How to Tie a Reef Knot\",\r\n    \"content\": {\r\n      \"$schema\": \"https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json\",\r\n      \"type\": \"AdaptiveCard\",\r\n      \"body\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"type\": \"TextBlock\",\r\n          \"text\": \"Contoso MainPage\"\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var response = await httpClient.PutAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/activities/{activityId}", contentForCreatingActivity);
            var stringifiedResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is also get method for retrieving all activities and it's also return bad request

```
public async Task<string?> IsUserActivityExistsAsync(Account account)
{
    string? resultSubject = null;

    var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync(account);
    if (accessToken != string.Empty)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/activities");
        var stringifiedResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return resultSubject;
}
```

All articles referencing that I have to provide correct scope but I took that scope from official microsoft docs and there wouldn't be a mistake.

Response for getting activities

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"ErrorCode\":2,\"ErrorMessage\":\"Substrate operation failed. Url: https://substrate.office.com/api/v2.0/users('******(73)')/CurrentCollections('******(10)') Status: Unauthorized. Error Code: invalid_tenant Error Message: The tenant for tenant guid 'tenant' does not exist., SubstrateError: null\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-12-29T05:44:57",
      "request-id": "id",
      "client-request-id": "id"
    }
  }
}
```

Response for adding activities

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"ErrorCode\":35,\"ErrorMessage\":\"General error occurred. Contact product team.\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-12-29T05:59:02",
      "request-id": "id",
      "client-request-id": "id"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please decode your access token in https://jwt.ms/ and provide the screenshot

Comment: @vickykumar hi. I have insert it to jwt.ms but im getting empty field. And I have tried with 100% valid one drive token the same here.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `UserActivity.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp` MS Graph API permissions are assigned to your app in Azure AD as Delegated type (not Application)

**UPDATED:**

Not sure if you're using correct authentication provider, for delegated type (check options here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS)

Try to acquire token by updating your code with the following changes

```
var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(MicrosoftConstants.ClientId)
    .WithTenantId("YOUR_TENANT_ID")
    .Build();
```

and

```
var authToken  = await publicClientApplication
    .AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync()
    .Result;
```

Note: Execute code under user account belonging to organization

Comment: If u about that. Yep I had. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/81jVFTR)

Comment: first of wall do I really need to use AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth instead of AcquireTokenInteractive? Because I don't want to be binded to logined windows account. And secondly if I add login by tenant then I have to add to organization each account in azure portal, right?

Comment: And also if I acquire token interactive and try to get user activities I am getting internal server error. I have updated my question, please check it out.

Comment: For Delegated permissions, you have to be binded to user account and organization (tenant), check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user. I suppose for files you used application permission, that's why it's ok. Interactive token also may be fine if retrieved with auth_code flow. As for your error it says you've specified tenant GUID incorrectly - you should pass tenant ID value from Azure AD. For MSAL the supported auth flows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are getting empty data when you decoded the access token in jwt.ms , which means you are doing something wrong while acquiring access token , follow the doc to get token via [Interactive provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#interactive-provider) , and then again check by decoding in jwt.ms .

```
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "common";

// Value from app registration
var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    // MUST be http://localhost or http://localhost:PORT
    // See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/System-Browser-on-.Net-Core
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential
var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response. But in my app Im using another tokens. For example with scope file.readwrite.all. And it is not decoding with jwt.ms also. But in app that token works fine.

Comment: How are you getting the access token ? if the token works fine in app , what is the problem you are facing then?

Comment: I mean token for one drive service not for activities